# drop down menu doesn't pop up

Tags: css, hover

I've created a simplified version of my situation here: https://jsfiddle.net/jyngjhpb/

In this example, the drop down part doesn't change it's opacity when the a above it is hovered:

```
a:hover + ul{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

In the real situation, the drop down part (nested ul) is hidden (display: none) and should also pop up whenever the 'parent' link is hovered. The a is hovered, as indicated by Chromes code inspector and the pointer as a cursor, but nothing happens.

I've also tried

```
li:hover ul{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

as the + might not work in the browser (after all you're also hovering the parent li), but this also fails.

I've looked up some people with similar problems but couldn't find anything helpful. Does anybody know what to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue deals with **specificity**. The `:hover` is not that powerful as your first rule. So change it to:

```css
#menuList ul {
  opacity: .3;
}
#menuList a:hover + ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

The reason behind it is, `id` attributes take much precedence over generic attributes. See the precedence here:

[image]

Example:

[image]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jyngjhpb/1/**

Comment: Thank you very much. My real situation now also works. I'll keep the specificity in mind.

Comment: @AxelKöhler Sure... :)

Comment: I have also located the source of your image and read the article from css-tricks on specificity. If anyone that is reading this is interested: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @AxelKöhler awesome... :)